# what does assembly mean in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i just read about the `Public` Access Modifier.

Its access levels are

1. Within the derived classes of that class available within the same assembly.
2. Outside the class within the same assembly.
3. Within the derived classes of that class available outside the assembly.
4. Outside the class outside the assembly.

What does assembly mean here?Can any one give any example

Comment: check ou there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk5f40ct(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_%28CLI%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An assembly is a DLL or Exe file

[Assembly (CLI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_%28CLI%29)

Comment: public modifier has access Outside the class outside the assembly. So does that mean public method in a class can be accesed by another project

Comment: @jade if the other project is referenced in your project, yes.

Answer (score 3):

An assembly is what would correspond to the contents of a single project in Visual Studio, or the contents of a DLL or EXE in built code.

Items with the access level `internal` are only visible and accessible to other code within the same assembly.

Comment: public modifier has access Outside the class outside the assembly. So does that mean public method in a class can be accesed from another project

Comment: Yes, that is correct, as long as your other project has a reference to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, usually, it means publicaly available outside the project (.csproj).  This is because projects usually define the assembly boundary (when a project is built into a dll or exe).

In constrast, the `Internal` access modifier will only allow access inside of a project (or assembly).